# orderby=meta_value_num creates duplicate posts

Tags: posts, order

I have my facebook likes stored in a custom field named fb_likes. my wordpress post order is sorted by this field, like this.

```
 'meta_key' => 'fb_likes',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
 'order' => 'DESC',
 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
 'posts_per_page' => $wp_query->get('posts_per_page'),
 'paged' => $paged
```

This seems to work fine at first glance, but if you click through the pages, you notice, that some posts are displayed two (or even three) times, even though they're in the database only one time. Also the post order is messed up and seems to change on its own.

When I use meta_value instead of meta_value_num it works fine, but then there's the problem that it sorts like this -> 9,5,4,39,38,37,26 - you get the idea. So I need meta_value_num to work as intended.

what could be the problem?

EDIT:
I use the following code to write the facebook likes to the meta_value of fb_likes. If I could just somehow write to the meta value like this "001" instead of this "1". Then I could easily use orderby=meta_value and wouldn't even need meta_value_num.

Is there a way to write to the database like this? 1 like -> 001, 21 likes -> 021

```
{
        if($post->post_type == 'draft') continue;
        $fb = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id='.get_permalink($post->ID)));
        if( !isset( $fb->likes) && isset($fb->shares) )
        {
            $fb->likes = $fb->shares;
        }
        //$fb->likes = isset($fb->likes) ? $fb->likes : 0;
        $this->log("post_id: ({$post->ID}) \npermalink: ".get_permalink($post->ID) . "\nfb_likes:". $fb->likes . "\n"); 
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'fb_likes', (int)$fb->likes);
    }
```

Comment: try echoing $wp_query->request after $wp_query->query() to see the actual sql.  run that sql in mysql workbench or w/e you use, and see what happens.  compare the sql and query results when you use meta_value vs meta_value_num.

Comment: something else that comes to mind: use meta_value as orderby, and then you can add a filter for the orderby clause and use (meta value * 1) to cast it as an integer.

Comment: @MikeLewis thanks for the help - meta_value_num is basically the same as meta_value+0. I changed meta_value+0 with meta_value*1 like you said, but it's just the same thing, it works exactly like meta_value+0 or meta_value_num. Please see my original answer (I edited it) because I have an idea now.

Comment: Maybe:  set post_status == publish?  revisions could be coming through as your duplicates.  Or is it post_type != revision, I forget how that works.  (Setting post_status and/or post_type could help)

Comment: Like Johannes said below, something else seems to be the issue. When running the raw SQL against the database, you should be able to figure out whats going on.  You might be best to just use a custom query.  I've been doing that a lot lately.

Answer (score 1):

As for the edit (leading zeroes):

```
/* will print "001" */
echo sprintf( "%03d", 1 );

/* will print "00097" */
echo sprintf( "%05d", 97 );
```

As for the inital problem:

Obviously, I believe your problem description, but if `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` does not produce duplicate results, neither *should* a change to `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`.
If that's the only alteration you make, it *should* only change order...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now - I just wrote to the meta_value field with leading zeros already attached and used the normal orderby=meta_value command. So now I have the likes already with leading zeros in my database.

```
$myfblikes = sprintf("%04s", (int)$fb->likes);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'fb_likes', $myfblikes);
```

Thanks for the help. I totally understand the point that it should also work with meta_value_num, because this command should really only change the post order. But somehow it doesn't - so there must be an issue with my meta_value_num. I don't even know how to put out raw sql because this is the first time I worked with php/mysql ;)

Anyways, I'm glad I got it working.